# How to export hair as object and not getting huge file

Tags: hair

Im new in Blender, and i made hair and export it as mesh,  myhair.obj file. But the file is enormous big. First it was 600Mb khmm.. Then i added decimate node and maximum (minimum) with that optimisation my file is still around 30 Mb big, and when is imported to Character creator 3 program become very slow, unresponding and myhair.obj file is importing long time, few minutes.
Mesh has 176,120 vertices, Faces 261,590,Tris 344,470. Hair becomes big after making mesh from particles. And also lose some fine details after "optimisation" and they are still to big, obviously.
If enyone can help, please tell me what have i missed in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately all "tips" I can give you will lower the quality of your result, but it will make the file size smaller.

Here is what you can do:

under *Emission*:

- lower *Number*
- lower *Segments*

[image]